# Combinatorics of multivariate Faà di Bruno formula

Tags: co.combinatorics

This question is a followup on [this one on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62558017/8425270) where i implement in python this issue. I am applying the Faà di Bruno formula to obtain the $\mathbf{i}$th derivatives of the function $f = ln \circ g$ in terms of the derivatives of $g$, a function with $n$ variables. This yield the following formula, denoting by $f^{(\mathbf i)}$ the $\mathbf i$th derivative of a function f

$$f^{(\mathbf i)}(t) = \sum\limits_{\pi \in \Pi(\mathbf{i})} (\lvert \pi \rvert -1) (-1)^{\lvert \pi \rvert -1} g(t)^{- \lvert \pi \rvert} \prod\limits_{B \in \pi} g^{(\mathbf{i}(B))}$$

where the notation follows [this section of the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Multivariate_version), plus a small variation that recover the multiindex $\mathbf i(B)$ from the set of dimension indexes $B$.

The problem is that, since the exponential function has all it's derivatives equal, as soon as we want to derivate twice on the same variable, i obtain several $\pi$ inside $\Pi(\mathbf i)$ that are equivalent.

For exemple, set $\mathbf i = (2,1)$ in a two-dimensional problem. Then, the partitions inside $\Pi(\mathbf i)$ are:

- $(0,0,1)$
- $(1), (0,0)$
- $(0), (0,1)$
- $(0, 1), (0)$
- $(0) (0) (1)$

There is here a partition that appears twice (without taking into account the order of blocks inside a partition), and which will have the same value into the sum.

This happends a lot (run my code from stackoverflow to find out). Is there a way i could 'factorise' the formula ?

Edit: For $n = 1$, in a one-dimensional problem, the formula indeed factorises to the Bell polynomials, and the number of occurences of similar partitions are the Bell numbers. Is there somewhere a multivariate equivalent ?

Edit: This problem is equivalent to finding all multiset-partitions of a multiset. The solution in term of multivariate partial Bell polynomials exists (see article in a comment), but the polynomials in question are still hard to implement.

Comment: Just a little comment: are you aware of this paper ? https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1996-348-02/S0002-9947-96-01501-2/S0002-9947-96-01501-2.pdf

Comment: @user69642 This is exactly what i need, precisely the Corrolary 2.10. Now i have trouble computing the $p(\mathbf \nu, r)$ set

Answer (score 1):

The Faa-di-Bruno formulae are really a clumsy ways of expressing the fact that (in the appropriate quotient algebra) *the Taylor polynomial of a composition is the (formal) composition of the relevant Taylor polynomials*. Working with formal Taylor polynomials should (I think) give you cleaner code and let you delegate most of the fiddly algebra/combinatorics to something like [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

You should be able to get the relevant composition rule by doing a Google-search for "composition rule for Taylor polynimials" or similar, but you can find it Chapter 1 of Malgrange's *Ideals of differentiable functions* if you need.

**Edit:** I thought I'd provide the following rough sketch just to illustrate what I mean... and because I couldn't resist having a go!

```
import sympy
import math

def get_indeterminates(n_indeterminates):
    return [sympy.Poly('X{}'.format(i)) for i in range(1, n_indeterminates+1)]

def monomial_from_multi_index(multi_index, indeterminates):
    monomial = indeterminates[0]**0
    if type(multi_index) is int:
        multi_index = (multi_index,)
    for x, power in zip(indeterminates, multi_index):
        monomial *= x**power/math.factorial(power)
    return monomial

def taylor_polynomial_from_partials(partials, indeterminates):
    """
    'partials' should be a dictionary mapping integer tuples to floats
    """
    Tf = 0
    for k, fk in partials.items():
        Tf += fk * monomial_from_multi_index(k, indeterminates)
    return Tf

def get_composite_taylor_polynomial(derivatives_of_f, partials_of_g, n_variables, truncation_order):
    x = get_indeterminates(n_variables)
    y = get_indeterminates(1)
    Tf = taylor_polynomial_from_partials(derivatives_of_f, y)
    Tg = taylor_polynomial_from_partials(partials_of_g, x)
    Tfog = sympy.polys.polytools.compose(Tf, Tg)
    return
```

Comment: This looks a lot like what i want; Except i'm using `mpmath` for precision, as Sympy will only have 60 digits or so and factorials add up quite quickly. But the spirit is exactly what i want, i'll try it